# How to refresh a page in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to refresh the page using jquery?
I am using

```
location.reload(true);
```

This code reloads the page i need to refresh the page(Once a page refresh user entered content would be there). how to refresh?

Comment: I really dont understand the question. But location.reload() will work, i dont think you need the true in there...

Comment: Refresh and reload are usually synonyms. Can you be more precise with what you're trying to do? `window.location.reload(true);` isn't what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use only `location.reload();` - note that this will not disable caching for the reload. But you cannot preserve both form fields **and** reload without using anything from cache.

It's very similar to F5 vs CTRL+F5: The first one does not disable all caching but preserves form fields. The latter does not load anything from cache and resets form fields.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK jQUery will not be helpful in this scenario.

If you are using HTML controls it will not preserve the value after refresh. If you want to preserve the value then you need to use server side controls.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in a function and do a return false.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `form` element `autocomplete="off"` that should do the trick