# How to resubmit PHP form with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am wondering if it is possible to to resubmit a form with a button click that calls up a javascript command.

So this is basically what I'm trying to do - 
page 1: form; action = page2.php 
page 2: generate a randomized list according to parameters set by page 1

I would like to place a button on page 2 so that on click, it would be as if the user has hit F5, and a new list would be generated with the same parameters.

I found a lot of help on Google with people trying NOT to get this to happen, but I'm not sure how to actually get it to happen.....

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `location.reload(true);` to refresh the page.

```
<button onclick="location.reload(true);">refresh</button>
```

Comment: So because I'm getting the data submitted by the form on page 2, if I just use location.reload, my form processing script tells me that it has no data to handle. I've tried history.go(0), and location.reload etc all the usual refresh commands with Javascript, and it hasn't worked

Comment: @user866339 Did you tried set the parameter to `true` as my example showed?

Comment: @user866339 Pages with submitted variables that you want to be able to revisit is what $_GET was designed for. Submit the form with `method="get"`.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to use. `location.reload()` instead of `location.reload(true)`. since this will not disable caching for the reload but using `true` as the parameter will.

here is the reference. [How to refresh a page in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324424/how-to-refresh-a-page-in-jquery)

EDIT: why not just use `hidden input field` and preserve the values and fetch it anytime you want to?

Comment: @user866339 then why not use hidden input field for preserving and changing values in `page2.php`.